# SQL Server: Concatenated string from Array of JSON objects

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a JSON string with n objects in DB like `[{"key1": "A", "key2": 22}, {"key1": "B", "key2": 32}, {"key1": "C", "key2": 42}, ....]`

Need to join all n objects to a single string of format `A22 B32 C42 ...`

How can I achieve this using a SQL function

Version: 2016

Comment: You want to concatenate per-row or combine all into a single row?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? This is a whole lot more doable in 2017, with actual support for JSON and string aggregation, than it would be on earlier editions. (Note that your current JSON isn't syntactically valid; you need quotes around string values.)

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Still missing the version (try `SELECT @@VERSION` if you don't know it). It's a one-liner in SQL Server 2017, if your objects all have the same structure: `SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(key1, key2), ' ') FROM OPENJSON('[{"key1": "A", "key2": 22}, {"key1": "B", "key2": 32}, {"key1": "C", "key2": 42}]') WITH (key1 NVARCHAR(MAX), key2 INT)`. In earlier editions, good luck, it'll be an exercise in suffering.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert Nice one. I just need to concatenate without `STRING_AGG`

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it in 2016 version from Jeroen Mostert's suggestion

```
SELECT 
    CAST(t.str as varchar) + ' ' AS 'data()' 
FROM 
    (   SELECT CONCAT(key1, key2) as [str]
        FROM OPENJSON('[{"key1": "A", "key2": 22}, {"key1": "B", "key2": 32}, {"key1": "C", "key2": 42}]') 
        WITH (key1 NVARCHAR(MAX), key2 INT)
    ) t 
FOR XML PATH('')
```